# Reducing 12 volts DC in a vehicle to 10.9 DC

Tags: resistors

I have a vehicle (12 volts DC) that has dash display that is too bright. If I install a potentiometer I can alter the power to get the display where I want it to be. This is 10.9 volts. If I read the potentiometer it reads 94 ohms.
I want to install an aluminum case wound resistor to accomplish the power drop but I can not figure out the correct unit I need. Any help would be great and thank you.

Comment: Most cars have a brightness control somewhere for dash display. 94ohms suggests only a small current (maybe 12mA), are these LEDs? If the current really is that small you only need a small resistor, not an aluminium clad one. IF you do need an aluminium resistor, what is it you need help with, you say you can't figure out which unit you need, what do you mean by unit? Sounds like you have the information there.

Comment: Why only resistor? Voltage in a car installation can vary from 10V to nearly 15V, use resistor (around 5 to 10\$\Omega\$) and zener diode rated for 11V.

Comment: The dash unit does have LEDs for its illumination. A VDO CB500 is what we are using.

For this application we ended up adding a dash dimmer display unit so that the unit can be controlled by the driver.

However, I still would like to understand how to get the correct resistor for next time.

Comment: The LEDs in the VDO dash unit are made to handle the voltage changes in the vehicles 12 volt system.
What I need to do it reduce the voltage in order to dim the LED illumination so that it is not so bright.
At 10.9 volts (from a rough normal running voltage of 13.5 volts) the dash illumination is the correct brightness.

Answer (score 2):

A chassis-mount resistor is overkill, but if you really want to do it (convenient mounting holes?) then you can use the smallest rating available (probably 5W): (photo from Digikey).

[image]

The closest standard values are 100\$\Omega\$ and 91\$\Omega\$, with 100\$\Omega\$ being more common. If you care about the difference between 100\$\Omega\$ and 94\$\Omega\$, you can add a 1/4-W resistor in parallel on top (put it in sleeving or shrink tubing).

The value required for the parallel resistor is 1/(1/94-1/100) ~= 1.6K

Comment: We installed a 5W 100 ohm resistor and it did not dim the LEDs in the dash.
I believe I am not calculating the values I need correctly.
That is the part I need help with.

Comment: If a 94 ohm pot works and a 100 ohm resistor does not, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Exactly. Hence why I am seeking advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a few more discrete parts on a pcb/breadboard, you could install you pot in [this circuit](http://www.rason.org/Projects/discreg/discreg.htm) (or a pre-made vReg, still controlled by your pot) to gain 2 major advantages (at least from my p.o.v.): 
This vReg. circuit compensates for different current draws (so a blinking turn signal indicator, etc. won't make your whole dash flash bright-dim-bright), and you're retaining the adjustability of having the pot in there, so you can easily re-adjust the brightness later, if needed.

Comment: This is basically what we did on this project (installed a dimmer for driver control). The illumination circuit is not tied into the flashers or anything else.

I still would like to know how to correctly find out what I would have needed to do this with a resistor.

Comment: If you don't mind a small amount of fluctuation with batt. voltage changes, you could use an "L-Pad" voltage divider to control the voltage to your dash display a bit more accurately than a simple series resistor can accomplish. The resistor to ground in the pad helps stabilize differences in voltage due to changing draw when different indicators turn on/off. Ref: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/attenuators/l-pad-attenuator.html